# How to find lost Safari password on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, password, mobile-safari

I need to know how to access a password that I lost on my iPhone. The password was saved using Safari but for some odd reason I can no longer access those passwords

Comment: Need more information, but I'll provide [this](https://www.imore.com/how-view-safaris-saved-passwords-and-credit-card-info-iphone-and-ipad) as a getting started, should it be a password that you saved in Safari. At this moment, your question is unclear, please see [How to Ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to edit your question to conform to the guidelines of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the password isn’t showing on the website you intend, you can retrieve it manually. Settings -> Passwords & Accounts -> Website & App Passwords.